# Can we add HTML code in the HTML Title tag?

Tags: seo, html, title, google-search

Can we add HTML code in the HTML Title tag. 
e.g.

```
<title>This is my page <b>Title</b></title>
```

And is there any impact of doing this on webpage and SEO.

Comment: Also I cannot even SEE your title in Chrome for example. What is the aim? For example you can give markup to google

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. The `<title></title>` is plain text.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a variable HTML title then best to use PHP or similar.

This will mean search engines will pick up "MAIN TITLE - Article Name" for example, if your website is database driven.